# Box packing with CSS

Tags: css

I'm trying to solve the classic box packing/knapsack problem with a CSS layout.

I would like to arrange many boxes in a way that minimizes whitespace between elements, like this;

[image: Image describing what I am trying to acheive]
<sub>(source: [tydus.net](http://tydus.net/img/xaZll.png))</sub>

CSS3 columns work VERY well here - boxes are arranged sequentially, but all white space is consumed efficiently. There is a teeny weeny problem - boxes are "sheared", or span across multiple columns. Can't do that.

I used the classic div.clearer after some boxes, but that had no effect - the boxes still spanned over those CSS3 columns. There is a column-span CSS property, but it's not supported in any browser yet ;(

Optionally, I could define the columns myself and arrange the boxes by hand, but realistically the boxes change height very frequently.

Final question: Is there a way to arrange boxes in a way that minimises whitespace between boxes using pure CSS?

Thanks!

Comment: Are the boxes block-level elements?

Comment: Yup, they're just div's. I experimented with display:block and display: inline-block.

Comment: Realistically, just use JavaScript: http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: I didn't correctly understand - what shall happen with a box that has greater height than the parent container?

Comment: CSS isn't aware of what is around it so I believe this is an impossibility, also you need to do calculations to see how much space you have left etc... If (I know you've probably already found it) you want to do it with js then have a look at: http://www.wookmark.com/jquery-plugin

Comment: The container should expand to meet the height of the largest box. It may be that one column contains only one very long box. A box should not span two columns.

Comment: @xconspirisist can you post something on jsfiddle.net so we can play around with it? I have a couple of ideas.

Comment: Can you show the existing CSS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I haven't tried it myself yet, one possible answer may be to use the [jQuery Masonry plugin](http://masonry.desandro.com/). This seems to fit the requirements you state.

Doing this in pure CSS and HTML willl be very hard, you'll have to probably let go of some wishes/requirements...

Comment: Or use Masonry's "big brother" Isotope, which can do Masonry layouts and much more. It's easy to implement. Another alternative is jQuery Tiles gallery which can be used with text also.